# How to open different content in popups on clicking html links

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I am using  following code.I want to open different content on click.

```
<style>
#overlay_form {
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 270px;
    height: 190px;
}
#pop {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
```

Following javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function () {
    //open popup
    $("#pop").click(function () {
        $("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
        positionPopup();
    });

    //close popup
    $("#close").click(function () {
        $("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
    });
});

//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup() {
    if (!$("#overlay_form").is(':visible')) {
        return;
    }
    $("#overlay_form").css({
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
        position: 'absolute'
    });
}

//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize', positionPopup); 
</script>
```

I want to use  something like following html

```
<html>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="pop" >Product Overview</a>
    <br/>
        <div id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
            <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>
        </div>

    <a href="#" id="pop" >User Interface</a>

        <div id="overlay_form" style="display:none">
            <a href="#" id="close" >Close</a>
        </div>
</div>

</html>
```

On clicking different links I want  to open different content in pop up.

Is is possible without repetition of whole java script with different ids.

Thanks

Comment: Why not inserting the whole code into a function and call it, while retrieving the caller id?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use the same id twice on the same page, you currently use `#pop`, `#close` and `#overlay_form` on both your links, update them with a class or different ids.

You could add a `div` inside each of your `a` tags that stores your content then just show/hide this on click?

Comment: Re: "a div inside each of your a tags" . . .Gah!  A block-level element inside an inline-level element?!?

Comment: I know I can not use same id twice, but is there any way to do what I want with minimal code? Thanks

Comment: yep with the html5 spec A tags can wrap block level elements

Comment: Oh yeah, in HTML5, but then we'd probably be using a `dialog` or an `article` or maybe even a `section`, depending on the context . . . not a `div`.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which you could do this, but the simplest one that uses your existing code, requires switching a lot of your id's to classes.  Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="pop" popup-id="popup1">Product Overview</a>

        <div class="overlay_form" id="popup1" style="display:none">
            <a href="#" class="close" >Close</a><br />
            Popup1 text.
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="pop" popup-id="popup2">User Interface</a>

        <div class="overlay_form" id="popup2" style="display:none">
            <a href="#" class="close" >Close</a><br />
            Popup2 text.
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //open popup
        $(".pop").click(function () {
            var targetPopup = $(this).attr('popup-id');
            $("#" + targetPopup).fadeIn(1000);
            positionPopup(targetPopup );
        });

        //close popup
        $(".close").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
        });
    });

    //position the popup at the center of the page
    function positionPopup(targetPopup) {
        $("#" + targetPopup).css({
            left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 2,
            top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form').width()) / 7,
            position: 'absolute'
        });
    }

    //maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
    $(window).bind('resize', positionPopup); 
</script>
```

This approach lets you use the class attribute to define a larger group of items that share the same behavior (as well as styles   :)   ), while still supporting the "uniqueness" of each popup.

Note: this makes use of a custom attribute (`popup-id`) which will not validate unless you update your `DOCTYPE` declaration to include it.  Many people simply overlook that issue, though, particularly since HTML5 is adding support for custom attributes.

**EDIT:** forgot to mention . . . since you are changing your IDs to classes here, you will also need to update your CSS `#pop` and `#overlay_form` to `.pop` and `.overlay_form`.

Comment: Why do you iterate through each .overlay_form? that is slow, you should pass id of particular popup to positionPopup();

Comment: Good point . . . I was focused more on the first part of the script and missed that.  Will update my answer.

Comment: Honestly, looking at it now, `positionPopup` probably doesn't even need to be a function . . .

Comment: you are right, it dosen't or it can have .fadeIn inside and just call that function

Comment: Oh well . . . designer decisions.   :)  Once he gets the solution to his problem, he can streamline as needed.